# How to read a large 30GB tar.xz with colab

Tags: python-3.x, google-colaboratory

I downloaded a 30GB tar.xz file to my G-drive using Google Colab. I need help in extracting and reading this folder in Colab. Inside the tar folder, there are ten folders. Is it possible to read these folders individually? I have tried the following but it failed.

1. Untar the 30GB folder in G-drive but it failed because of the limitations with reading and writing files in G-Drive.
2. I can directly download the file to the local Colab directory, but because of the space limitations in Colab I cannot extract or read it in the local directory.

Any suggestion about how to proceed with this problem.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can extract only a directory inside the tar file, using `--wildcards` option.

```
!tar xf file.tar.xz --wildcards 'path_to/dir/*'
```

Here's an [example notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1xi-73IG3humn1kFcCEd0X56jcPDbZPwE?usp=sharing).

Comment: there are a problem after extracting all these files it take much time to be updated in the Gdrive . and some times not updated . do you have any solution for this