# How do I open a .gz file from a website in Goolgle colab?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I need help downloading a .gz file in Google colab. The file is here but I can't download it on my local drive due to the size, it's 8 GB. I have tried to different ways to do it but I'm stuck.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

file https://mcfp.felk.cvut.cz/publicDatasets/IoT-23-Dataset/iot_23_datasets_small.tar.gz

Comment: Here are the same questions as you and the [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69964788/how-to-unzip-gz-file-using-google-colab).

Comment: I added !tar -xzvf "/content/iot_23_datasets_small.tar.gz" "/content/drive/path/destination_directory"                                                               but got this error:
tar: /content/drive/path/destination_directory: Not found in archive
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors

Comment: I also have a way to download the file and then unzip it. See this:[https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1xi-73IG3humn1kFcCEd0X56jcPDbZPwE?usp=sharing](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1xi-73IG3humn1kFcCEd0X56jcPDbZPwE?usp=sharing) [this answer link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64767000/how-to-read-a-large-30gb-tar-xz-with-colab)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `curl` to download and `tar` to extract it.

```
url = 'https://mcfp.felk.cvut.cz/publicDatasets/IoT-23-Dataset/iot_23_datasets_small.tar.gz'
!curl {url} | tar xz
```

It should take around 15 minutes. The files will be extracted here

```
/content/opt/Malware-Project/BigDataset/IoTScenarios
```

See this [example notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/186rs6gIAonjKgNLceBnV26i997y_62_h?usp=sharing)